# ajax to location.replace(ajax.responseText) reloads forever

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web

I can't figure out why this is happening, and there is no documentation of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HideSite</h1>
<script>
var ajax;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    location.replace(ajax.responseText);
}
if (navigator.userAgent == 'code') {
    ajax.open("POST", "location.txt", true);
    ajax.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

location.txt contains the location of a file.

## Update:

Instead of the `replace()` I inserted this: `alert(ajax.responseText)`. It did it three times, and only on the third did the window actually contain anything.

```
if (ajax.responseText != undefined && ajax.responseText != "") {
        alert(ajax.responseText);
}
```

When I added this it only did it twice, both times containing the correct string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onreadystatechange` event gets hit multiple times during the life of an AJAX call; a majority of these hits will not actually be delivering any response text. The ready states are as follows:

```
0: request not initialized 
1: server connection established
2: request received 
3: processing request 
4: request finished and response is ready
```

Being as you've said *"on every state change"* rather than *"when the response is ready"*, more often than not your AJAX call has not yet received the response. I would suggest modifying your event to include an `if` statement like so:

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (ajax.readyState == 4) {   //WHEN RESPONSE IS READY
      location.replace(ajax.responseText);
   }
}
```